# Insert and update operations don't refresh data after use filters operations on datatable (Primefaces)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I've insert, update and filter operation on datatable component of Primefaces. This operations work normally. The problem happen after use filter operations. This happen so:

1. I make insert and update operations with AJAX. Datable's data is refreshed normally
2. I use filter operations (filter datatable's feature). This work normally. Then the filters back to their initial values
3. I make again insert and update operations on datatable component. Data is updated on database but doesn't refresh on component. I have to refresh the page again in order to refresh the data on datatable. I don't understanh that happening...

This is normal behavior of datatable component?

I'm using PF 3.5

Comment: DO you update datatable after insertion? item 1 and 3 say contararly?

Comment: In both cases I update datatable. In item 1 this update work but item 3 is not. Anyway, I already solved the problem con this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339855/ajax-update-doesnt-work-when-using-filter-on-datatable-jsf-primefaces)

Comment: This is expected, filteredata is another list, you need to add your data to the filteredData as well to keep two lists in sync. PrimeFaces Filtering does not and should not change your original data, it create a new data out of filtering.

Comment: @CesarMiguel maybe this answer helps you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339855/ajax-update-doesnt-work-when-using-filter-on-datatable-jsf-primefaces/14340944#14340944)