# primefaces datatable filter do not work in subsequent clicks

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a primefaces view in which i filter a specific column (Task Status) using a drop down list. When i choose a value from the filter list for the first time, filter works ok, but in subsequent filter selections the table is not refreshed (my view is dead).

Here is the view code:

```
<p:dataTable id="tasksDataTable"
        var="cRTaskData" 
        value="#{taskCenterBean.cRTaskList}"
        widgetVar="tasksTable" 
        paginator="true"
        sortMode="multiple"
        filteredValue="#{taskCenterBean.cRTaskListFiltered}" 
        rows="10"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20,30" 
        paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">
    <p:ajax event="filter" update="@this"/>
    <p:column sortBy="#{cRTaskData.taskId}" headerText="ID" style="width:40px;text-align:center;">
        <h:outputText value="#{cRTaskData.taskId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column filterBy="#{cRTaskData.status}" 
            filterMatchMode="exact" 
            filterOptions="#{taskCenterBean.cRTaskListOptions}" 
            headerText="Task Status" style="width:110px;text-align:center;">
        <h:outputText value="#{cRTaskData.status}" />
    </p:column>
    ...
    <p:column style="width:90px;text-align:center;">
        <p:commandButton value="View" 
            action="#{imageBrowserBean.openTaskInEditor(cRTaskData.taskId)}"                                        
            icon="ui-icon-image" />                     
    </p:column>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

and here the relevant back bean code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "taskCenterBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TaskCenterBean implements Serializable  {
    private final static String[] cRTaskStatuses = {"Open","Submitted","Closed","Conflict"};
    private List<CRImageData>   cRTaskList;
    private List<CRImageData>   cRTaskListFiltered;
    private SelectItem[]        cRTaskListOptions;

    public List<CRImageData> getcRTaskList() {
    return cRTaskList;
    }

    public List<CRImageData> getcRTaskListFiltered() {
    return cRTaskListFiltered;
    }

    public void setcRTaskListFiltered(List<CRImageData> cRTaskListFiltered) {
    this.cRTaskListFiltered = cRTaskListFiltered;
    }

    public SelectItem[] getcRTaskListOptions() {
    return cRTaskListOptions;
    }

    private SelectItem[] createFilterOptions(String[] data)  {  
        SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[data.length + 1];  

        options[0] = new SelectItem("", "Select");  
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
            options[i + 1] = new SelectItem(data[i], data[i]);  
        }  

        return options;  
    } 

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TaskCenterBean(){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CRTask.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("reviewerId", ConfigOptionsBean.getCurrentUser().getUserId()));
        cRTaskList = criteria.list();
        session.close();    

        cRTaskListOptions = (SelectItem[]) createFilterOptions(cRTaskStatuses);
    }
    ...
}
```

Any ideas what i have been missing? The logic is identical to the one featured in the relevant primefaces demo.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is simmilar to this one: [Ajax update doesn't work, when using filter on p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339855/ajax-update-doesnt-work-when-using-filter-on-datatable-jsf-primefaces)

Try calling tasksTable.filter() after the ajax call is made:

```
<p:ajax event="filter" update="@this" oncomplete="tasksTable.filter()" />
```

Comment: Is CRImageData.status a String? Can you try to change `update="@this"` to `update="@form"`?

Comment: Yes it is a string! Changed to "@form" without any luck (view got broken)