# Ajax update of datatable from a modal after filtering

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

My question is very similar to this: 
[Ajax update doesn't work, when using filter on datatable (JSF, Primefaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14339855/934307).

I have a `dataTable` with an "Open" button (a `commandButton`) for each entry/row in the table, on click of which, a `dialog` will open. I have a form in the dialog that I can update and save. Once I save my changes, I will get back on the `dataTable` closing the dialog I'm in, updating the results of the save that happened in the dialog on the entry in the table (whose "Open" was clicked to open the `dialog`).

If I save the results from the `dialog` and use the `update` attribute to update the results of the save on the table entry, it works fine. However, if the `dataTable` was filtered in the first place and then the `dialog` was opened, then the `update` does not result in update of the table entry until I actually refresh/reload the page.

The

`oncomplete="PF(':parentForm:dataTableVar').filter()"`

and

`oncomplete="PF(':parentForm:dataTableVar').clearFilters()"`

solutions recommended in the other question I referenced don't seem to have any effect in my case.

Any suggestions?

---

I use JSF v2.1.19 and PrimeFaces v5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake to mention the `id` in place of the `widgetVar`. This:

```
oncomplete="PF('myTableWidget').filter()"
```

would work fine if the `dataTable` in question looks like:

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable" widgetVar="myTableWidget"...
```

I was wrongly trying it this way:

```
oncomplete="PF('myTable').filter()"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark the list in the attribute `filteredValue` on dataTable.
Ex: `<p:dataTable filteredValue="#{bean.anotherListWithTheSameType}" />`

In dialog, it's necessary filteredValue.
From here: http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/dataTable.html

Comment: Is that it? I just specify a list to hold the filtered objects? Where do I really use that list? Just trying to understand how it is related to the problem I;m facing.