# Primefaces grid was not updated after executing remote command

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, filtering

I have a dataTable with filters on columns and option to delete a row. When the table is in intial state, if I delete row, the table is updated. If I apply the filter, and delete one of shown rows, the result of the filtering remains, until I refresh the page or change the filter.

Here is the code:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="tdataTable" var="tdata" value="#{oemModel.models}" widgetVar="oemModelsTable" editable="true" editMode="cell"
                scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500" paginator="true" rows="15" 
                             emptyMessage="No tdatas found with given criteria" filteredValue="#{oemModel.filteredOemModels}">
    </p:dataTable>

               <p:dialog id="deleteModelDialog" header="Delete " widgetVar="deleteDialog" appendTo="@(body)" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" height="150" width="350" modal="true" resizable="false" >
                    <h:panelGroup id="deleteModelPanel">
                        <div align="center">
                            <h:outputText value="Are you sure?" />
                            <p>
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                    <p:commandButton value="Yes" icon="ui-icon-check" onclick="PF('waitDialog').show();deleteModel();" />
                                    <p:commandButton value="No" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="PF('deleteDialog').hide()"/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:dialog>

                <p:remoteCommand name="deleteModel" update="tdataTable" actionListener="#{bBean.deleteModel}" oncomplete="PF('waitDialog').hide();PF('deleteDialog').hide();"/>
 </h:form>
```

And in backingBean, I'm deleting it from database, and loading data again:

```
public void deleteModel() {
        try {
            service.deleteOemModel(selectedModel.getId());
            models= service.getOemModels();
        } ...
    }
```

where the models is the binded list.

Any hints? I have tried to change the update attribute on remotecommand, to update the whole form, but nothing helps.

Comment: where is the datatable?

Comment: I have added it now to the question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter again, because the filter is cached.
As described in this example [Ajax update doesn't work, when using filter on p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339855/ajax-update-doesnt-work-when-using-filter-on-datatable-jsf-primefaces)
you should try:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="deleteModel" update="tdataTable" actionListener="#{bBean.deleteModel}" oncomplete="PF('waitDialog').hide();PF('deleteDialog').hide(); PF('oemModelsTable').filter()"/>
```

Try it with PF and without, I'm not into Primefaces in this moment :D

Comment: awesome!! this is the thing I needed!

Comment: The thing you needed is in the duplicate ;-)